# Failed to resolve dependency android

Tags: android, gradle, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to add exoplayer dependency version `2.12.2` and getting the below error

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.12.2
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Gradle version `7.2`

Top level build gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ext.line"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.12.2"
}
```

And the settings gradle file

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using `jcenter()`

Applicable to exoplayer versions below `2.13.3`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}` in settings.gradle.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried and doesn;t work

Comment: The correct syntax is: maven {
    url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" ) 
}